# Is there an LNCS alternative to \newtheoremstyle of amsthm?

Tags: lncs, newtheorem

I find the `\newtheoremstyle` of `amsthm` very handy.
As far as I know, LNCS class have only `\spnewtheorem` which allows to change only the head font and the body font. In contrast, `\newtheoremstyle` allows to change more (e.g.: puncuation after theorem head, amount of space before/after the theorem environment).
**Is there an LNCS class command that gives more control similar to `\newtheoremstyle` of `amsthm`?**

Here is an mwe.

```
  \documentclass{llncs}
  \spnewtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}{\bfseries}{}

  %\documentclass{article}
  %\usepackage{amsthm}
  %\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
  %\newtheoremstyle{freethm}% <name>
  %{3pt}% <Space above>
  %{3pt}% <Space below>
  %{}% <Body font>
  %{}% <Indent amount>
  %{\bfseries}% <Theorem head font>
  %{}% <Punctuation after theorem head>
  %{.5em}% <Space after theorem headi>
  %%{\bfseries}% <Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')>
  %{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}.\\}
  %\theoremstyle{freethm}
  %\newtheorem{mytheorem2}{Theorem}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{theorem}[LNCS/asmthm style]
  A nice theorem.
  \end{theorem}
  \begin{mytheorem}[LNCS spnewtheorem]
  Another nice theorem.
  \end{mytheorem}
  %\begin{mytheorem2}[amsthm newtheoremstyle]
  %Another nice theorem.
  %\end{mytheorem2}
  \end{document}
```

This gives the following output:
[image]

When I uncomment the line `\usepackage{amsthm}`, I get the error "Command \proof already defined.". I suppose this is because `llncs.sty` includes and redefines many theorem environments (and also proof environment) of amsthm. Anyway, it seems possible to ignore this error. But, when the `\newtheoremstyle` command is uncommented, I get error that are impossible to ignore.

Comment: is there some reason you can't use amsthm with that class?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My understanding is that `llncs.sty` redefines theorem environment of `amsthm`. So, I don't know a way to use amthm with that class. If you can point out a way to do this, that will be a perfect answer.

Comment: I don't have the class and you provided no link and no test document. If you provided a small test document using amsthm with llncs.cls and said what error you got, someone could debug.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Sure. Please see the updated question (mwe added).

Comment: if I uncomment your newtheoremstyle I get `! You can't use \`macro parameter character #' in vertical mode.` even in article class, without using llncs at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `amsthm`, provided you remove the `proof` environment as defined by the document class.

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\let\proof\relax\let\endproof\relax
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{freethm}% <name>
 {3pt}% <Space above>
 {3pt}% <Space below>
 {\itshape}% <Body font>
 {}% <Indent amount>
 {\bfseries}% <Theorem head font>
 {}% <Punctuation after theorem head>
 {\newline}% <Space after theorem headi>
 {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}.} % Head spec

\theoremstyle{freethm}
\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}



\begin{document}

\title{Contribution Title\thanks{Supported by organization x.}}

\author{First Author}

\authorrunning{F. Author}

\institute{Some University, Someplace\\\email{first.author@someuniversity.edu}}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
The abstract should briefly summarize the contents of the paper in
150--250 words.

\keywords{First keyword  \and Second keyword \and Another keyword.}
\end{abstract}

\section{First Section}

Please note that the first paragraph of a section or subsection is
not indented. The first paragraph that follows a table, figure,
equation etc. does not need an indent, either.

Please note that the first paragraph of a section or subsection is
not indented. The first paragraph that follows a table, figure,
equation etc. does not need an indent, either.

\begin{theorem}[Standard]
This is a theorem in the standard style.
\end{theorem}

Please note that the first paragraph of a section or subsection is
not indented. The first paragraph that follows a table, figure,
equation etc. does not need an indent, either.

\begin{mytheorem}[Free]
This is a theorem in the free style.
\end{mytheorem}

Please note that the first paragraph of a section or subsection is
not indented. The first paragraph that follows a table, figure,
equation etc. does not need an indent, either.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to preserve the `proof` environment as defined by the class, you can do as follows:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% save the proof environment defined by the class
\let\lncsproof\proof \let\lncsendproof\endproof \let\lncsqed\qed
% remove the definitions in order to load amsthm
\let\proof\relax\let\endproof\relax

\usepackage{amsthm}

% restore the class defined proof
\let\proof\lncsproof \let\endproof\lncsendproof \let\qed\lncsqed

\newtheoremstyle{freethm}% <name>
 {3pt}% <Space above>
 {3pt}% <Space below>
 {\itshape}% <Body font>
 {}% <Indent amount>
 {\bfseries}% <Theorem head font>
 {}% <Punctuation after theorem head>
 {\newline}% <Space after theorem headi>
 {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}.}

\theoremstyle{freethm}
\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}



\begin{document}

\title{Contribution Title\thanks{Supported by organization x.}}

\author{First Author}

\authorrunning{F. Author}

\institute{Some University, Someplace\\\email{first.author@someuniversity.edu}}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
The abstract should briefly summarize the contents of the paper in
150--250 words.

\keywords{First keyword  \and Second keyword \and Another keyword.}
\end{abstract}

\section{First Section}

Please note that the first paragraph of a section or subsection is
not indented. The first paragraph that follows a table, figure,
equation etc. does not need an indent, either.

Please note that the first paragraph of a section or subsection is
not indented. The first paragraph that follows a table, figure,
equation etc. does not need an indent, either.

\begin{theorem}[Standard]
This is a theorem in the standard style.
\end{theorem}

Please note that the first paragraph of a section or subsection is
not indented. The first paragraph that follows a table, figure,
equation etc. does not need an indent, either.

\begin{mytheorem}[Free]
This is a theorem in the free style.
\end{mytheorem}

Please note that the first paragraph of a section or subsection is
not indented. The first paragraph that follows a table, figure,
equation etc. does not need an indent, either.

\begin{proof}
This is a proof in the standard style.\qed
\end{proof}

Please note that the first paragraph of a section or subsection is
not indented. The first paragraph that follows a table, figure,
equation etc. does not need an indent, either.

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, if you don't restore and remove the `\qed` at the end of the proof, you get

[image]

which seems much alike the other picture (and is easier to maintain because you don't need to manually add `\qed`).

Comment: Isn't `\let\proof\relax\let\endproof\relax` relaxing the proof environment defined by `llncs`? I suppose this is not acceptable when explicitly asked to write with the llncs class (isn't it?). Anyway, your solution works.

Comment: @CyriacAntony I added how to restore the original `proof` environment (although I don't think it's necessary, read the comments).

Comment: Great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `\newtheoremstyle` declaration gives errors even if used with `article` class. There appears to be a spurious final line using `#` that has been copied from a `\newcommand` or similar construct.

If I fix that, then the code works unchanges with a copy of llncs that I found at

[https://www.win.tue.nl/~setalle/tex/llncs.cls](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Esetalle/tex/llncs.cls)

if you ndefine the proof environment to let `amsthm` define it.

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{llncs}

\let\proof\undefined
\let\endproof\undefined
\usepackage{amsthm}

 % \spnewtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}{\bfseries}{}

\newtheoremstyle{mytheorem}% <name>
{3pt}% <Space above>
{3pt}% <Space below>
{}% <Body font>
{}% <Indent amount>
{\bfseries}% <Theorem head font>
{}% <Punctuation after theorem head>
{.5em}% <Space after theorem headi>
{\bfseries}% <Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')>


%??????{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}.\\}

\newtheorem{ztheorem}{theorem}

  \begin{document}
 
  \begin{ztheorem}[LNCS spnewtheorem]
  Another nice theorem.
  \end{ztheorem}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Please see the modified question. Code needed for amsthm is added (but commented out). The code runs perfectly when the lines for LNCS are commented out and lines for `amsthm` are uncommented.

Comment: The line marked with “theorem head spec” is wrong; the ninth argument to `\newtheoremstyle` should either be empty or contain something like in the next line with `\thmname`, `\themnumber` and `\thmnote`.